# How to grow Image width after opening lightBox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm using [react-native-lightbox](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox) for an image viewer, and when I open the image I want to take a full-screen width, but it doesn't do that; it just takes a default width before it opens. I'm using the width and height as a state and, when opening the lightbox, for updating the value, but that didn't work (it gave the error "lightbox Not Working".) So, how do I  handle these images to take full width and height?

[image: befor opened]

[image: after opened]

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
import Icon from "react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons";
import Lightbox from "react-native-lightbox";

import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Image,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  Dimensions
} from "react-native";
const { width, height } = Dimensions.get("window");
class GalleryScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [],
      widthX: width / 3 - 17,
      heightX: 110,
      flexO: 0
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref(`providers/${uid}`)
      .on("value", snapshot => {
        let uri = snapshot.val().Images;
        let images = [];
        Object.values(uri).forEach(img => {
          images.push({ uri: img.uri });
        });
        this.setState({ images });
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <FlatList
          numColumns={3}
          key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)}
          data={this.state.images}
          style={{
            alignSelf: "center",
            marginTop: 10,
            marginBottom: 0
          }}
          renderItem={({ item }) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity style={{ margin: 5 }}>
                <Lightbox
                  underlayColor="#fff"
                  style={{ flex: 1 }}
                  backgroundColor="#001"
                >
                  <Image
                    key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)}
                    source={{ uri: item.uri }}
                    style={{
                      alignSelf: "center",
                      width: width / 3 - 17,
                      height: 110,
                      borderRadius: 15
                    }}
                    resizeMethod="resize"
                    resizeMode="cover"
                  />
                </Lightbox>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        />
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            alignItems: "center",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignSelf: "flex-end",
            width: 70,
            height: 70,
            right: 20,
            bottom: 15,
            borderRadius: 50
            // backgroundColor: "#fff"
          }}
        >
          <Icon name="ios-add-circle" size={70} color="#2F98AE" />
          {/* <Text style={{ fontSize: 40, color: "#fff" }}>+</Text> */}
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default GalleryScreen;
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#f1f1f1"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set size for outer container intead of the image and give the image with width and height 100% so that when the lightbox shows up, the image will take a full-screen size

```
<TouchableOpacity 
  key={Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)} 
  style={{ margin: 5, width: width / 3 - 17, height: 110 }}
>
  <Lightbox
    underlayColor="#fff"
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    backgroundColor="#001"
  >
    <Image
      source={{ uri: item.uri }}
      style={{
        borderRadius: 15,
        width: "100%", 
        height: "100%"
      }}
      resizeMethod="resize"
      resizeMode="cover"
    />
  </Lightbox>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: you should move this 'width / 3 - 17'  to outside render to avoid recalculating everytime render is called

Comment: thank u, but I got blank screen without any images, like this [https://i.imgur.com/NRqs4zZ.png] @CuongTranDuc

Comment: that's my bad, now I got this? so how to force the lightbox to take a full-screen "lightbox background it's **blue**", look at this, https://i.imgur.com/7PVs8IM.png  and when I change the                       resizeMode to "contain", every image in the Gallery take a deference width and Hight so how to just force them to take a default width and Hight when rendering as you see here  https://i.imgur.com/xEpjqXi.jpg ? @CuongTranDuc

Comment: @OliverD if the lightbox doesn't take a full-screen maybe it's problem with the library

Comment: what you mean by force images take a default width and height, it will stretch full the outer container with resizeMode cover(not remain the ratio size) or zoom out inside the container with resizeMode contain(keep the ratio)

Answer (score 1):

lightBox have property called (`activeProps`). for make image full screen just delete `style={{ flex: 1 }}`. and add that property. set its value like this:

```
activeProps={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}}
```

as reference check this out : https://github.com/oblador/react-native-lightbox

Answer (score 0):

You should use for example:

```
<Lightbox
  activeProps={{
    style: {
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
    },
  }}

>
</Lightbox>
```

with this code you can style the image under lightbox when it is open.